# TideSDK with Python: except Exception as e: ...make TideSDK use Python 2.7

Tags: python, exception, tidesdk

**EDIT:**

I just noticed that TideSDK uses Python 2.5 (it comes in the SDK) and that this syntax I'm using is indeed invalid syntax in that version.

Now the question is, how can I make TideSDK use Python 2.7?

---

I'm using TideSDK 1.3.1-beta and TideSDK Developer (1.4.2).

I want to write a Desktop app using TideSDK and embed some python code.

When I write code in Python using "except Exception as x", in example:

```
try:
    pass
except Exception as x:
    pass
```

I get the following error (as seen in the Webkit "Web Inspector"'s console) and the code doesn't run:

```
[23:58:21:913] [Ti.Python] [Error] An error occured while parsing Python on the page: ('invalid syntax', ('', 5, 23, '    except Exception as x:\n'))
```

---

I tried it with inline code and with inserted code but still got the same error.

Inline code:

```
<script type="text/python">
    try:
        pass
    except Exception as x:
        pass
```

Inserted code:

```
<script type="text/python" src="test.py"></script>
```

---

I can use:

```
except Exception:
    pass
```

but not:

```
except Exception as x:
    pass
```

Any hints on what's going wrong?

Comment: What Python version are you using?  That syntax was added in Python 2.7.

Comment: Wow! you are fast...

I just noticed exactly that, TideSDK is using 2.5.

I have 2.7 installed, but I don't know how to make TideSDK use that version...